# Split Design into parent table and child OR have one with all data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Suppose I have a `Transactions` relation and it can be either a `Sell` or a `Buy` transaction. Each transaction have different set of `Items` with different quantities.

`Sell` and `Buy` have different attributes.

**So I have thought of several ways:**

1) Having a schema where there is a parent relation `Transaction` that have 2 childs `Sell` and `Buy` and the `Transaction_Items` relation link to `Transaction`

```
Transaction:(id, date)
Sell:(Transaction.id, Supplier.name)
Buy:(Transaction.id, Employee.name, Customer.name)
Transaction_Items:(Transaction.id, Item.id, quantity)
```

Problem here is that I can't find primary key for `Sell` and `Buy`

2) Merge `Sell`, `Buy` and `Transaction` into one relation and for example if it is a buy transaction then the `Supplier.name` will be null.

```
Transaction:(id, date, Supplier.name, Employee.name, Customer.name)
Transaction_Items:(Transaction.id, Item.id, quantity)
```

3) Have separate relation for representing a sell transaction or a buy transaction and each have its own transaction items relation

```
Sell_Transaction:(id, date, Supplier.name)
Buy_Transaction:(id, date, Employee.name, Customer.name)
Sell_Transaction_Items:(Sell_Transaction.id, Item.id, quantity)
Buy_Transaction_Items:(Buy_Transaction.id, Item.id, quantity)
```

Can you please tell me which is more suitable to use and why you rolled out the others? Also if you have any other thoughts to other ways please do tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 would be the best option. Subclassing transactions into the sell and buy components will make for more involved views of the data, but will save space in the long run.

Comment: and it is okay to use foreign key as primary key?!

Comment: Yes, It indicates subclassing. Take care with Auto_increment or identity columns. You want this feature only on the highest superclass, and then echo that PK into the subclass tables when you insert into them.